# Need a way to identify a specific variable type using a key on a string

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to convert this to a specific value to use in the replaceAll()? The problem I am running into is that the program is replacing the specific spot rather than the type of variable.

```
var input = "a=1 a"
var letter = {input:1} 
var letterVal = {input:3}
var replaceletter = input.replaceAll(letter, letterVal)
```

Comment: The snippet as given doesn't make sense. You're using input as a key in lines 1 and 2, but then you're using it as a variable on line 3.

Comment: That is my problem. I need to convert this key to a variable.

Comment: Okay. Do you want the word "input"?

Comment: Input is a string. I want if the string is "1=a 1", the string will change to "a=a a."

Comment: Actually, reverse that; "a=1 a" > "1=1 1"

Comment: So like `input.replaceAll(input.substr(0, 1), input.substr(2, 1));`?

Comment: I think that this might work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this method (I'm new to javascript).

Comment: Please, also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145525/2610061 . `String.replaceAll()` is a new feature (August 2020) and will not work in IE and in node.js.